# labels column shape is inconsistent after splitting data into features and labels

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shapes

I have a dataset as pandas dataframe that needs to be divided into feature set and labels. as of now, I am dividing the columns as below,

```
features = df2.drop('case_of_injury_group', 1)
labels = df2['case_of_injury_group']
```

but the shape of labels is not as what I expected,

```
features.shape
```

give (39778, 12) and

```
labels.shape
```

gives (39778, ) but I want it as (39778, 1). Please let me know what i am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1):

If want one column `DataFrame` select by one element nested list:

```
labels = df2[['case_of_injury_group']]
```

Comment: Worked. Thanks !!